# Spivak Calculus on Mainfolds 1-7(b)

Tags: manifolds, linear-transformations

Prove that a norm-preserving transformation $T$ is 1-1 and $T^{-1}$ is of the same sort.

I am having trouble seeing the correlation between norm-preserving and 1-1?

Comment: what question are you talking about?

Comment: It's impossible to understand this question without having the book on hand.

Comment: @PJK I'm sorry. I've updated the question.

Comment: @littleO I apologize, I've updated the question

Comment: transformation defined on? only norm preserving does not necessarily imply $1-1$

Comment: Can you show that if $T$ is norm preserving then its kernel is $\{0\}$?

Comment: @PJK on $R^n -> R^n$

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is linear, then it is sufficient to show that $\ker T=0$. So if $Tx=0$ then $||Tx||=0\Rightarrow ||x||=0\Rightarrow x=0$. Now if $T$ is linear, so is $T^{-1}$ and also $\ker T^{-1}=0$ as well.